# Changing a constraint's second item changes the constant to a negative value

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard

In my view hierarchy, I already set constraints for a label (New In.top), which is tied to the bottom of a collection view (top collection view.bottom), but I had to add a new view which is a horizontal stack view in between and then edit the previously set constraints to satisfy the new stack view that was added, I tried to change the label's top constraint which was previously tied to the collection's view bottom to have it tied to the new stack view's bottom instead (male/female stack view.bottom) but then it gives a  and when I change the negative constant to a positive one, it gives an error, I already tried deleting the whole top constraint of the label to add a new one but the new stack view doesn't show up as an option to tie it to[, take a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIKy1.jpg).

WHAT I'M TRYING TO ACHIEVE.

[From this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suN5W.png)

I'm trying to place the horizontally stacked black buttons ("male" and "female") in between the label sticking out from the left side of the black buttons stack view and the collection view with a UIImageView in it to the top of the buttons stack view without any constraint error.

[This is the constraint error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZBAp.png)

These are the constraints set for all the views in the error above

[The constraints set for "male/female stack view"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akE91.png)

[The constraints set for "Top collection view"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JoLc.png)

[The constraints set for "Product collection view"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsMxx.png)

[The constraints set for "PageControl"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBBKP.png)

[The constraints set for "flash stack view"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJglC.png)

Comment: "it gives an error" What error?

Comment: A missing constraints error for all previously set views, precisely “Need constraints for: Y position or height” but then these views already have the constraints Xcode is asking for, in fact they were working fine before I had to add the new stack view in between

Comment: Then that means there isn't enough information from the constraints that you added for Xcode to figure out a position and size for each of the views after you changed the constant to positive. Try to figure out what the missing constraints you need are, and add them. Note that IB automatically adjusts the constants when you change the second item in order to maintain the position and size of the view. But from what I understand from your question, you don't want that, so change it to positive, and figure out what new constraints you need to add.

Comment: If you are stuck, you can [edit] your question to describe, with screenshots and words, the layout that you are trying to create, and include the constraints that you have added so far. Then we can help you add some more constraints.

Comment: Take a look now, I included what you asked as best as I could